# Unable to serialize kiebase in drools-engine 8.29.0.Final

Tags: java, serialization, drools, rules, rule-engine

Since the SessionsAwareKnowledgeBase implements KieBase which can't be serializable.

Struggling from the past one week.

Usecase: Need to serialize the kiebase and store into the database.
At runtime i have to deserialize the kiebase.

Tried with Marshalling kiesessions and save it in the database, But when pulling out from the database we need even kiebase to unmarshall.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why were you serializing the KieBase?

Comment: Instead of creating Kiebase everytime on the fly, want to store the Kiebase in the file system and use it when it is required.

Comment: Storing the KieBase for performance.

Comment: Hi @NaveenReddy, were you able to resolve or workaround this problem? I am facing the same issue while migrating/upgrading.

Comment: @DevDot Didn't find a solution yet.